# Password required field on email auth and redundant activation mail

Tags: python, django, django-socialauth

I am using python social auth to perform different social authentication.

When using the email auth supplied in the example, it is working fine and sends an activation mail. But password is not a required field. What I want to do is, that on registration and login via email to have the password a mandatory field.

My other struggling is the redundant activation mail sent. I don't want to send an activation mail everytime a user tries to signup with the same mail. If the user sign's up the first time I send the mail. On the second time, I need to notify the user that he needs to activate his account.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

To enforce password you need a custom pipeline function to do the check

```
def password_check(strategy, user, response, *args, **kwargs):
    if not user.verify_password(response['password']):
        raise AuthFailed(strategy.backend, 'Wrong password')
```

For the second problem, you can override the default email-validation pipeline entry with your custom behavior.

Comment: when trying the password_check is called on mail registration. It raises error 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'verify_password'.

Comment: Put the entry after `'social.pipeline.user.create_user'`.

Comment: I did so, but I still get the same error, but now after entering the activating link. which doesn't satisfy my need at the first place, because it does send the activation mail even though I didn't enter a password on registration.
Another thing to modify the email verification mechanism, in order to send the activation link once. How can I find the user has already tried once. The app doesn't seem to save the user unless he is activated ..

Comment: Looks like there's an error while creating the user, it's a custom user model?

Comment: But if the problem was in creating the user. It wouldn;t have worked before adding the password_check pipeline. I have an extra userprofile model which has a one to one relation with the basic user model.

Comment: @SalmaHamed, could you join me in the IRC channel #python-social-auth at freenode?

Comment: I'm facing a very similar issue. Have you found a solution? Could you please share it here?